# Openshift route is not accepting traffic yet because it has not been admitted by a router

Tags: openshift, redhat, openshift-origin

We have deployed a container from Apache HTTP Server (httpd) 2.4 template. After deployment successful, we are facing issue for assign route.

Error: The route is not accepting traffic yet because it has not been admitted by a router.

Version
OpenShift Master:
v3.7.0+7ed6862
Kubernetes Master:
v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last, find out the root cause of this issue. The router pod was not running on OSE master node, after starting the router pod it is working fine.

Comment: How did you start the router pod?

Comment: On the default project, one router deployment should be there. I had just scale up and down that deployment.

Answer (score 0):

```
oc rollout latest dc/router -n default
```